# Grails run-app error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, grails

A week ago I could run my grails app just fine. Now all of a sudden it's not working anymore. I'm a nooby to grails and am not used to reading this stack traces. Could someone take a look at this and point me in the right direction?

```
| Error 2014-08-20 23:16:51,989 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'controllerHandlerMappings': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'openSessionInViewInterceptor_datawarehouse' while setting bean property 'interceptors' with key [2]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'openSessionInViewInterceptor_datawarehouse': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory_datawarehouse' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory_datawarehouse': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'lobHandlerDetector_datawarehouse' while setting bean property 'lobHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDetector_datawarehouse': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)
Message: Error creating bean with name 'controllerHandlerMappings': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'openSessionInViewInterceptor_datawarehouse' while setting bean property 'interceptors' with key [2]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'openSessionInViewInterceptor_datawarehouse': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory_datawarehouse' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory_datawarehouse': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'lobHandlerDetector_datawarehouse' while setting bean property 'lobHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDetector_datawarehouse': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)
    Line | Method
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread

Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'openSessionInViewInterceptor_datawarehouse': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory_datawarehouse' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory_datawarehouse': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'lobHandlerDetector_datawarehouse' while setting bean property 'lobHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDetector_datawarehouse': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread

Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory_datawarehouse': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'lobHandlerDetector_datawarehouse' while setting bean property 'lobHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDetector_datawarehouse': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread

Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDetector_datawarehouse': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread

Caused by MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread

Caused by SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)
->> 1549 | createPoolableConnectionFactory in org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1388 | createDataSource in     ''
|   1044 | getConnection in     ''
|    262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread

Caused by CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
->>  411 | handleNewInstance in com.mysql.jdbc.Util
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1117 | createCommunicationsException in com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError
|    350 | <init> .  in com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO
|   2408 | coreConnect in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|   2445 | connectOneTryOnly in     ''
|   2230 | createNewIO in     ''
|    813 | <init> .  in     ''
|     47 | <init>    in com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection
|    411 | handleNewInstance in com.mysql.jdbc.Util
|    399 | getInstance in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|    334 | connect . in com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver
|     38 | createConnection in org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory
|    582 | makeObject in org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory
|   1556 | validateConnectionFactory in org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
|   1545 | createPoolableConnectionFactory in     ''
|   1388 | createDataSource in     ''
|   1044 | getConnection in     ''
|    262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread

Caused by ConnectException: Operation timed out
->>  339 | doConnect in java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    200 | connectToAddress in     ''
|    182 | connect . in     ''
|    392 | connect   in java.net.SocksSocketImpl
|    579 | connect . in java.net.Socket
|    528 | connect   in     ''
|    425 | <init> .  in     ''
|    241 | <init>    in     ''
|    259 | connect . in com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory
|    300 | <init>    in com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO
|   2408 | coreConnect in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|   2445 | connectOneTryOnly in     ''
|   2230 | createNewIO in     ''
|    813 | <init>    in     ''
|     47 | <init> .  in com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection
|    411 | handleNewInstance in com.mysql.jdbc.Util
|    399 | getInstance in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|    334 | connect   in com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver
|     38 | createConnection in org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory
|    582 | makeObject in org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory
|   1556 | validateConnectionFactory in org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
|   1545 | createPoolableConnectionFactory in     ''
|   1388 | createDataSource in     ''
|   1044 | getConnection in     ''
|    262 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
```

Comment: I assume you tiried deleting the target folder(s) and cleaning the projects? Gets rid of most random errors i ecountered.

Comment: Actually no. I'm really a nooby to this so when you say target folders, do you mean the root folder where i'm trying to run "grails run-app" also when you say clean what do you mean by that?

Comment: When you compile your project, it will create a folder named `target` that is the directory you can delete without harming your project.  I always feel nervous just outright deleting things in the project that I didn't make, so I usually move it to another directory until I can be sure it doesn't contain something I need to be safe.  Another option is just to run the command `grails clean-all` and then try the run-app again.  

It's been my experience that doing a `clean-all` will cause weird exceptions to be thrown the first time I run app afterwards, but it works every subsequent times.

Comment: also check your **/DataSource.groovy.  There should be config for a `datawarehouse` db.  Check, that whatever driver and connections is configured there works.

Comment: that did not do the trick but I'll keep it in my back pocket

Comment: yeah cfrick nailed it. I work on this with a bunch of backend engs and haven't worked with grails before and didn't even understand where to look for that kind of stuff but they added some driver that broke my checkout.